# firing different query in postgres based on condition returned by another query

Tags: postgresql, conditional-statements, postgresql-9.2

Based on the result returned by one sql query, I have to decide which SQL query to call. Is it possible?

Following is a demo:

```
select start, end, max from table.
If max < 10
 select ob1, ob2, start, end from t1
if max >=10 and < 50
 select ob1, ob2, start, end from t2
if max >= 50
 select ob1, ob2, start, end from t2
```

Comment: max is integer, start and end are dates, ob1, ob2 is integer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like *conditional union*:

```
select ob1, ob2, q2."start", q2."end"   
from (
    select "start", "end", "max"
    from the_table
    ) q1,
lateral (
        select ob1, ob2, "start", "end"
        from t1 
        where "max" < 10 
    union
        select ob1, ob2, "start", "end" 
        from t2 
        where "max" >=10 and "max" < 50 
    union
        select ob1, ob2, "start", "end" 
        from t3
        where "max" >= 50 
    ) q2
```

Read about [LATERAL Subqueries](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL) in the documentation.

In Postgres 9.2 one can use `with` query:

```
with m as (
    select "max"
    from the_table)
select ob1, ob2, q."start", q."end"   
from (
        select ob1, ob2, "start", "end"
        from t1, m 
        where "max" < 10 
    union
        select ob1, ob2, "start", "end" 
        from t2, m 
        where "max" >=10 and "max" < 50 
    union
        select ob1, ob2, "start", "end" 
        from t3, m
        where "max" >= 50
) q
```

Comment: Hey... lateral keyword doesn't work for postgres 9.2... is there any alternative for 9.2?

Comment: I did it in the same way.. was wondering if there is any alternative for lateral... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE OR replace FUNCTION fnn ()
RETURNS setof t1 AS $$
DECLARE sql TEXT;
BEGIN
    SELECT CASE 
            WHEN max < 10
                THEN 'select ob1, ob2, istart, iend  from t1'
            WHEN max >= 50
                THEN ' select ob1, ob2, istart, iend  from t2;'
            WHEN max > 10
                THEN ' select ob1, ob2, istart, iend  from t3;'
            END AS qry
    INTO sql
    FROM itable;
    RETURN QUERY
    EXECUTE (sql);
END $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

usage:

```
select * from fnn()
```

or

```
DO $$
DECLARE sql TEXT;
BEGIN
    SELECT CASE 
            WHEN max < 10
                THEN 'select ob1, ob2, istart, iend  from t1'
            WHEN max >= 50
                THEN ' select ob1, ob2, istart, iend  from t2;'
            WHEN max > 10
                THEN ' select ob1, ob2, istart, iend  from t3;'
            END AS qry
    INTO sql
    FROM itable;
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t;
    EXECUTE ('create temp table t as ' || sql);
END $$;

select * from t;
```

Comment: I didn't like this answer b/c it presented the solution by creating a function however I do think the usage of the case statement is better than the current answer using a WITH clause.